# Magento 2: Refused to apply style from

Tags: javascript, magento2.3.2

Anyone can help me this problem, the issue in this link the screenshot below
http://prntscr.com/p9qypy
Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you explain clear solution for this problem?

Comment: I try many times run deploy but still same issue.